# How to copy file from applicationStorageDirectory into dataDirectory?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like to copy an image file located in `www/assets/imgs/christmas.jpg` to the `dataDirectory` folder using the [Ionic Native File Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/), however I don't know how to access the `www` folder. I tried the following:

`this.file.checkFile(this.file.applicationStorageDirectory, 'assets/imgs/christmas.jpg')`

But it always returns `NOT_FOUND_ERR`.

Comment: Did you try it with `www` in front of the file path (so instead of `assets/imgs/christmas.jpg` use `www/assets/imgs/christmas.jpg`)? I can imagine that the storage directory contains the `www` folder and not the contents of the `www` folder. You may also have to use `applicationDirectory` instead of `applicationStorageDirectory` although I am not sure what the difference is.

Comment: you're right: `this.file.checkFile(this.file.applicationDirectory, 'www/assets/imgs/christmas.jpg')` seems to be working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `applicationStorageDirectory` to `applicationDirectory` (although I am not sure what the difference is) and add `www` in front of the file path as the application directory contains the `www` folder and not its `contents`. So instead of `assets/imgs/christmas.jpg` use `www/assets/imgs/christmas.jpg`